# How do I produce output in NASM matching `81 /0 iw` for `ADD r/m16, imm16` on x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code

I am going through the [ADD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) instruction on x86 Intel docs, one line at a time, and trying to reproduce it so I can learn how their obscure notation works and figure out how to generate machine code without gcc/clang/llvm/etc..

I am stuck currently on the `81` opcode pair:

```
81 /0 iw    ADD r/m16, imm16    MI  Valid   Valid   Add imm16 to r/m16.
81 /0 id    ADD r/m32, imm32    MI  Valid   Valid   Add imm32 to r/m32.
```

What are two examples (one for each) of NASM instruction calls that will generate output matching these patterns and generating output starting with `81` for each?

When I try what I think would work, I get completely different output:

```
add ax, 6553
```

Becomes:

```
66 05 99 19
```

From this:

```
bits 64
global start
section .text
start:
  ADD ax, 6553
```

And

```
nasm -f macho64 test.asm
```

I can get the `83` ones working, like:

```
83 /0 ib    ADD r/m16, imm8
```

That works like this:

```
bits 16
global start
section .text
start:
  add ax, 1
```

But the 81 ones don't work, and it only differs by `imm16`, I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned somewhere in the beginning: the `66` prefix toggles between 16 and 32 bit operand size.  In 16 bit modes, 16 bit operand size is the default.  In 32 and 64 bit modes, 32 bit is the default operand size.  As the instruction list applies to all operation modes (unless specified otherwise), it doesn't show where the `66` prefix is used as it's always used in the same way for scalar instructions (but beware of SSE instruction where the prefix is used for a different purpose).

And about your `add ax, 6553` instruction: the assembler chooses the shorter `add ax, imm16` encoding here.  Chose a different register than `ax` to avoid this effect.

Perhaps try

```
add cx, 1234
add ecx, 1234
```

and perhaps for good measure

```
add rcx, 1234
```