# Why does `add cx, 1234` in NASM 16 bit mode produce <unknown> with objdump?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code, objdump

I have this:

```
bits 16
global start
section .text
start:
  add cx, 1234
```

With this Makefile:

```
test:
    @nasm -f macho64 test.asm
    @objdump -x86-asm-syntax=intel --full-leading-addr -d test.o
.PHONY: test
```

It prints:

```
% make

test.o: file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64


Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000000000000 start:
      0: 81 c1                          <unknown>
      2: d2 04                          <unknown>
```

Why does it produce the `<unknown>` and not show the instruction here? Did I do something wrong? Still learning the very basics of machine code so sorry if it's obvious.

It seems to work fine in 32 bit mode:

```
bits 32
global start
section .text
start:
  add cx, 1234
```

Outputs:

```
% make

test.o: file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64


Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000000000000 start:
      0: 66 81 c1 d2 04                 add cx, 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opcode `81` in 64-bit mode requires 5 more bytes (modrm + imm32), but your `.text` segment ends before that so the disassembler gives up.  If you pad the text section with some more bytes (like `times 10 db 0`), you'll get something.

You used `bits 16` to put non-64-bit machine code into a 64-bit object file, so of course you should expect things to be wrong in general.

16-bit mode has a different default operand-size (16) than 32 and 64-bit mode (32), so the `66` operand-size prefix makes things opposite.  Instructions that require a `66` prefix in 32 or 64-bit mode (like `add cx, 1234`), require it to be absent in 16-bit mode.  (As mentioned in [@fuz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948401/how-do-i-produce-output-in-nasm-matching-81-0-iw-for-add-r-m16-imm16-on-x8) to your previous question)

Comment: By 64-bit object file, that's what `nasm -f macho64 test.asm` macho64 is doing, is that what you mean? How do I generate a 16 bit object file then is what I should be doing I guess. I don't there is one of those though, so 32 bit, but I'll still run into the same problem probably.

Comment: @LancePollard: Yes, that's what tells `objdump` what mode to assume when disassembling it.  `bits 16` / `mov cx, 1234` is *exactly* the same as `db 0x81,  0xc1, 0xd2, 0x04` in terms of the contents of the `.o`, including metadata.  An assembler literally just assemblers bytes into the output file at the current position (in the current section, for files other than flat binary)

Comment: Excellent, that helps clarify some things, thank you!

Comment: @LancePollard: For 16-bit disassembly experiments, probably easiest to make a flat binary: `nasm -fbin test.asm` / `ndisasm -b16 test`.  (`-f bin` is actually the default for NASM; you'd use that to make stuff like legacy sectors, or to manually emit the bytes of MachO or ELF metadata for an executable, like in this tutorial: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.)  Or `objdump` does have options to control what mode to assume for disassembly of a `.o` if you do choose to put code of the wrong bitness in a 32 or 64-bit object file.  Or `nasm ... -l/dev/stdout` listing